# Type issue when setting access_control settings from enviroment variables

Tags: symfony4, symfony-security

I am setting ip and port to restrict certain routes in symfony and passing ip and port settings from environment variables as follow:

**.env.local**

```
AC_API_IP="127.0.0.1"
AC_API_PORT=8080
```

**services.yaml**

```
parameters:
    ac.api.ip:  '%env(AC_API_IP)%'
    ac.api.port:  '%env(int:AC_API_PORT)%'
```

**security.yaml**

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: '%ac.api.ip%' , port: '%ac.api.port%'}
    - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Which is not working ans getting type error as:

> Argument 4 passed to
>   Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension::createRequestMatcher()
>   must be of the type integer or null, string given,

I also tried this without any luck:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: '%ac.api.ip%' , port: '%env(int:AC_API_PORT)%'}
    - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Comment: What if you remove the quotes? `port: %ac.api.port%` instead of `port: '%env(int:AC_API_PORT)%'`

Comment: @ArleighHix, I think that is not possible

Comment: I came around this by defining voter service